# Writing Junit test case for a class with @JobScope, got error as java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'job'

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit

*Got this error while executing test cases -  No Scope registered for scope name 'job'*

> My class looks like:

```
     @Service  
     @JobScope  
     public class JobService{

        @Value("#{jobParameters['abc']}")
        private ABC abc;

        @Override
        public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        .......
        }
      }
```

> [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzbNM.png)  My test class looks like:

```
     @TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, JobScopeTestExecutionListener.class })  

    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)  
    public class JobServiceTest{  

    public JobExecution getJobExecution() {  
            JobExecution execution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createJobExecution();  
            execution.getExecutionContext().putString("input.data", "foo,bar,spam");  
            return execution;  
        }  

        @Test  
        public void beforeJobTest() {  
            jobService.beforeJob(getJobExecution());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Exception say that annotation Jobscope doesnt exists.
Why you want to use this annotation?

Comment: i m using @JobScope annotation to fetch jobparameters

Comment: Rename jobscope for example in Job There are a couple of spring annotations that have Scope at the end: ApplicationScope,SessionScope. I think spring search for all annotations that ends with Scope.

Comment: But i am needing Jobscope in my logic. i have other classes with stepscope and i am facing the same error as No Scope registered for scope name 'step'

Comment: Just rename those annotations!

Comment: what should i rename? I need those annotation.

Comment: sorry , i thought you created this annotation for your own. I didnt know, that it from spring

Answer (score 1):

Adding @EnableBatchProcessing to the test class worked for me... but I'm not sure if you want to put this on a test class.  It's probably better to use a Config class and import the configuration in your test class.

```
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, JobScopeTestExecutionListener.class })  
@EnableBatchProcessing
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)  
public class JobServiceTest{  

    public JobExecution getJobExecution() {  
        JobExecution execution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createJobExecution();  
        execution.getExecutionContext().putString("input.data", "foo,bar,spam");  
        return execution;  
    }  

    @Test  
    public void beforeJobTest() {  
        jobService.beforeJob(getJobExecution());
    }
}
```